# Login authentication always returning true

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, razor, webforms

My code is querying a server which, if the user and password are correct, returns the "+" character. Otherwise it doesn't. Bad practice, but I am just using this idea to learn C# and ASP.NET which I am a beginner at (I've wrote the program in JSP previously).

My problem :

- Currently, I seem to have some error which causes my methods to
  always return true. This should not be the case. It should only be
  true when the usersname/pass are authenticated.
- I want it to display the login form only if the user is not logged in
  and a session has not been started - what is the best way to adapt my
  code to do this?

My code so far :

```
   @{
    // Initialize general page variables
    string username = "";
    string password = "";
    bool rememberMe = false;

    // Validation
    bool isValid = true;

    // If this is a POST request, validate and process data
        if (IsPost) {
            username = Request.Form["username"];
            password = Request.Form["password"];
            rememberMe = Request.Form["remember"].AsBool();

            // Attempt to login to the external authentication server
            if(isValid){
                using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient("hosty.host.com", 110)) {
                using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream()) {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream)) {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream)) {
                    writer.WriteLine("USER " + username );
                    writer.WriteLine("PASS " + password );
                    string response = reader.ReadLine();
                    isValid = response[ 0 ] == '+';
                    Response.Write(response);
                    writer.WriteLine("quit\n");
                }
                }
                }
                }
            }

            if (isValid) {
                <text>IT WORKED---></text>
            //USER LOGGED IN/ SESSION STARTED


            } else {
                <text>IT DIDNT WORK :( </text>
                //USER NOT LOGGED IN, SESSION NOT STARTED
            }
        }
    }   
        <h2>Login Here</h2>
        <form action="" method="post">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Login Form</legend>
            <label for="username">Username:
              <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" />
            </label>
            <label for="password">Password:
              <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" />
            </label>
            <label for="remember">
              <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" checked="checked" />
              Remember me</label>
            <p>
              <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login" />
              &nbsp;
              <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
            </p>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Comment: Please avoid including things like `C#/Razor/ASP.NET` in your question title. That is what the tags are for.

Comment: You can stack Using statements (Nested statements) so there is no need for so many sets of curly brackets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You start with `isValid=true` but if your program can not even be able to connect to the server the `isValid` is remain true.

So maybe your users not even validate at all, you start with isValid and end with the same even if the validation is not done.

The code as it is, I will start it with false, and remove one line.

```
// Validation
    bool isValid = false;

    // If this is a POST request, validate and process data
        if (IsPost) {
            username = Request.Form["username"];
            password = Request.Form["password"];
            rememberMe = Request.Form["remember"].AsBool();

            // Attempt to login to the external authentication server
            // if(isValid)
            {
                using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient("hosty.host.com", 110)) {
                using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream()) {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream)) {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream)) {
                    writer.WriteLine("USER " + username );
                    writer.WriteLine("PASS " + password );
                    string response = reader.ReadLine();
                    isValid = response[ 0 ] == '+';
                    Response.Write(response);
                    writer.WriteLine("quit\n");
                }
                }
                }
                }
            }

            if (isValid) {
                <text>IT WORKED---></text>
            //USER LOGGED IN/ SESSION STARTED


            } else {
                <text>IT DIDNT WORK :( </text>
                //USER NOT LOGGED IN, SESSION NOT STARTED
            }
        }
```

Also be ware that Page.`IsValid` is an existing parameter on web form.

Comment: (joke : if login authentication always return true, then show the important information's to the non authenticated users :)

Comment: Haha, yes this is a (slightly) cut down version of my full program. I append on some more information in the full version. I have adapted to use your changes now, but unfortunately it still always says that it has authenticated (prints "IT WORKS!")!

Comment: @SimonKiely can you debug your code to see what response have on return ?

Comment: I am trying to do this (Response.Write(response); in my code above) but nothing is rendered on screen. What is the best way to display this code? Apologies, silly question I know, but I am only beginning C#.

Comment: OK, I have a new error with this. The response string is holding "+OK Dovecot ready.". I believe this just indicates that the POP3 server is ready to accept connections, but it is not providing any authentication? If I try to call 'reader.ReadLine();' multiple times, I enter an infinite loop. Any ideas?

Comment: @SimonKiely This is something that you need to investigate with your response data from the email connection because I do not know what you get on return. To authenticate with the email... I think you need to search a little on this what the email return, what are the commands... etc.